# webdriver-sync running asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, synchronous

I'm trying to create selenium tests that run each step synchronously, without using .then(), or async/await. The reason for this is that I want to create a set of functions that allow pretty much anyone on our test team, almost regardless of tech skills to write easy to read automated tests. It looks to me like webdriver-sync should give me exactly what I want. However, the following dummy code is producing problems:

```
var wd = require('webdriver-sync');
var By = wd.By;
var Chromedriver = wd.Chromedriver;
var driver = new Chromedriver;
driver.get('https://my.test.url');
var myButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('[id*=CLICK_ME]'));
myButton.click();
```

It tries to run - browser is launched, and page starts to load... but the steps are not executed synchronously - it goes on and tries to find and click "myButton" before the page has finished loading, throwing a "no such element" error... which to me kinda defeats the point of webdriver-sync?! Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

FWIW, I have webdriver-sync 1.0.0, node v7.10.0, java 1.8.0_74, all running on CentOS 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the same error with firefox driver?

Comment: Really need this working with Chrome, but nonetheless I just tried switching to FF. Using the instructions on github.com/jsdevel/webdriver-sync to instantiate the FF driver, I get: "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property" - but I can't see how to set this with node.js?

Comment: the only time I used selenium webdriver with nodejs I used webdriver.io and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put double-quotes around "CLICK_ME" as it's a string value.

Generally, though, it's a good idea to Wait for specific elements because dynamic pages are often "ready" before all their elements have been created.